# Does a memory barrier tame Microsoft's optimizer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, memory-management, cl.exe

I'm working on a multi-platform, multi-compiler library. The library has the following macro:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1400)
# pragma intrinsic(_ReadWriteBarrier)
# define MEMORY_BARRIER() _ReadWriteBarrier()
#elif ...
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# define MEMORY_BARRIER() __asm__ __volatile__ ("" ::: "memory")
#else
# define MEMORY_BARRIER()
#endif
```

Under GCC, the code above can be used to tame the optimizer. 
Though the function is called `MEMORY_BARRIER`, the important part is the inline assembly marked `volatile`. That's the part that tames the optimizer under GCC, Clang and Intel.

***EDIT***: The inline assembly does not tame the optimizer on Clang, even though Clang claims to be GCC by defining `__GNUC__`. See [LLVM Bug 15495 - dead store pass ignores memory clobbering asm statement](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15495).

The use of the macro is a `handle` class. The `handle` provides one level and indirection, and we are trying to induce a NULL pointer dereference to help locate bugs (some hand waiving). To achieve our goal, we need to ensure the optimizer does not remove the dead store (`m_p = NULL;`):

```
template <class T> handle<T>::~handle()
{
    delete m_p;
    m_p = NULL;

    MEMORY_BARRIER();
}
```

I don't want to use a `volatile` cast because (1) I don't believe its the correct use of the qualifier (taken from interactions with the Clang and GCC devs), and (2) it appears the `volatile` cast is undefined behavior in C++ (see [Approved way to avoid lvalue cast warnings and errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31768707)).

Does a memory barrier tame the optimizer on Microsoft platforms?

Comment: As an alternative solution, if you want to set `m_p` to zero with no concern about it being optimized away, you can use `SecureZeroMemory()` when Windows is the target.  For other targets you can perhaps call some other API or an assembly function?

Comment: @Michael - yes, agreed. If I could re-use the memory barrier code, then it tidies things up nicely by hiding the implementation specific details behaind the macro (and without the need for more macros and the `_Pragma`, and all the conditionals that accompany it).

Answer (score 2):

Under GCC compiler you can turn off optimization for selected functions manually   with compiler directives like in the example below.

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")
static inline void MEMORY_BARRIER() {
    // your code
}
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Under VC compiler you can turn off optimization for selected functions manually with compiler directives like in the example below.

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
static inline void MEMORY_BARRIER() {
    // your code
}
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

Maybe you can use this tricks to get what you want?

Unfortunately I do not now how to do similar trick under clang/llvm or Intel Compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I moved away from that exact code (but I forgot to tell you why...). Visual Studio lets you control optimizations for Professional and Enterprise editions, and not the Learning and Community editions (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg (written in C, not C++) addresses this problem by having [a wrapper for `free`, which zeroes the pointer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/group__lavu__mem.html#ga0cc84043ea2167ad005c86e11d0bcdba).

In new code they prefer `av_free(&ptr)` over `av_free(ptr)`.

If there is a use-after-free condition, the compiler won't be able to prove it's a dead store and eliminate it, I guess.  This might not work in C++, if the compiler is allowed to assume that writes to member variables in a destructor are dead stores.

I know it wouldn't prove anything, but have you seen cases where the compiler optimizes away these pointer-zeroing stores?

Comment: *"... have you seen cases where the compiler optimizes away these pointer-zeroing stores?"* - yes.

Comment: Does it still happen if you on-purpose include a use-after free?  Maybe by having a member function return the address of a member variable to code that saves it.  Or even just having the member variable public.